# Strange version shown for a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML version of one of my existing app. I set the package version to 1.5.0.0, the created file is called SlovakApps.WindowsPhone_1.5.0.1_AnyCPU_bundle.appxupload. When I upload the file to Dev Center, a strange version is shown:

[image]

Is this normal? Seems very strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft support:

> Yes this is very normal now when you are submitting a package to
>   support Windows Phone 8.1, it automatically generates an version
>   number for your update.

Comment: Really, is it normal? I have the same problem, this strange version number shows in store too. I didn't find any official source about that.

Comment: I do not think is normal but the do not seem to want to do anything about it

Answer (score 1):

Do not create bundle. Generate and upload just *.appxupload* package.

[MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64bb6d2d-f27a-4944-a28b-f7c545970d7f/windows-81-unmodifiable-and-incorrect-package-version?forum=windowsstore)