# Wrong version number submitted to Windows Phone Store. Is it possible to correct this?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I deployed an app to the Windows Phone Store and the version number that got deployed is different than the version in the app manifest.

The version that got deployed is something like 2014.MMDD.ABC.XYZ

It should have been 1.0.0.0.

Why was the version number changed, and is it possible to change it to what it should be?

Comment: It's some kind of internal Store version number, when you get your app's version number from `Package.Current.ID` it will be 1.0.0.0.

Comment: I can see in the app store that all the other apps have 'normal' version numbers. Mine is the only one with a crazy looking one.

Comment: When I submit my beta app I've the same problem and I don't now how to change it. Some time ago there was a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978936/strange-version-shown-for-a-windows-phone-8-1-xaml-app/24003614#24003614). I'm not sure if it's not connected with appx bundle.

Comment: You're not the only one. Don't worry. With my universal app I have the same version number. It has something to do with bundles.

Comment: It falls neatly in line with everything else Microsoft have managed to make a balls of with Windows these days. It's as if in their desperation to copy Apple, they also decided to copy the stuff that developers hated. Hopefully Windows 10 will resolve most of these issues.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/deb78a46-e64c-4dc2-b1b4-8d1c24230fe8/app-bundle-gets-version-2014?forum=wpsubmit) thread this is expected behaviour for app bundle packages.

Rob writes:

> This is expected behavior for app bundle packages. They are always
>   versioned based on date. The code package will have its set version
>   information. If you list the packages on your Windows system in
>   \Program Files\WindowsApps you'll see this is the case for all app
>   bundle packages.
>   --Rob

Bill Chung writes:

> if the option "Generate app bundle" set to "never", the version number
>   will be normal.

Comment: Thanks for the response this version mismatch was driving me crazy

Answer (score 2):

That is the version for your appxbundle, not for the app itself. The bundle contains the resources so only the relevant ones are installed on any specific devices. The app itself should still show up with the right version in the store.

If you look in Program Files/WindowsApps on your desktop you'll see the same thing there: many apps will have both the normal package and timestamp-versioned bundle packages.

Comment: Thats not correct. The version shown in the store app is still the date-based version. The "correct" version is only used in the list of app installs/updates.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The numeric format is definitely the way appxbundles are versioned.  I don't see any date versioned apps in a quick run through the store. Where exactly are you seeing this? If it's systematic then let me know and I can get a bug filed. If you're seeing a problem with your specific app then you can contact support at http://aka.ms/storesupport for help tracking down what is wrong.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have just updated with a new package, maby it will get solved then. Here is an example with that strange version number: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/brew-mate/e006dc73-4d1c-47d3-871a-cace972e4ca3

Comment: Our app is still listed as beta, so there's no link I can give you. However, I just checked Buddhas app which has the same issue as ours.

Comment: Example (universal app): http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/instalike/66c9129a-4376-408c-9ee7-f7b2cfbd9575